# How to let EMR execute customer jar first

Tags: hadoop, compression, emr, bzip2

Because hadoop 1.0.3 doesn't support bzip2 decompress, so I copied the same classes from hadoop 2.2 into my project, but my project (or we call it jar) is still running on hadoop 1.0.3 cluster. I found hadoop still execute the the classes from 1.0.3 i.e the new classes were not executed.
How can I configure to use the classes in myself's jar firstly. 
I know we may use something like:
 hadoop jar collect_log.jar com.TestCol **-Dmapreduce.task.classpath.user.precedence=true**
But right now I'm using EMR, so I don't know how to set the precedence in EMR.
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EMR referees its hadoop jars from location /home/hadoop/lib 
You can try using bootstrap scripts to copy your new jars to this location.

Other option is when you launch emr . Connect to master node using ssh and key file and see ps -ef | grep java.

it will show current hadoop process and its jar orders ( class path)
Later you can make changes in Bootsraop script to change class paths a per your new order

edited to add sample bootstrap script mybootstrap.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
hadoop fs -copyToLocal s3n://bucket/bootstrap/abc.jar /home/hadoop/lib/
```

upload this script to s3 bucket and assign it to emr launcher code as

```
        RunJobFlowRequest request = new RunJobFlowRequest(.....
        ScriptBootstrapActionConfig bootstrapScriptConfig = newScriptBootstrapActionConfig();
        bootstrapScriptConfig.setPath(CONFIG_HADOOP_BOOTSTRAP_ACTION);

        BootstrapActionConfig bootstrapConfig = new BootstrapActionConfig();
        bootstrapConfig.setName("copy jar file");
        bootstrapConfig.setScriptBootstrapAction(bootstrapScriptConfig);
        request.withBootstrapActions(bootstrapConfig);
```

Here CONFIG_HADOOP_BOOTSTRAP_ACTION will be path for your bootstrap file.

Comment: Thank you so much Sandesh, could you please give an example how to use bootstrap scripts to copy new jars to hadoop lib location or make changes in Bootstrap script to change classes paths by new jar orders please.

Comment: @Jack , I have edited my answer with sample bootstrap script to copy any file to your cluster